# game engine fps animate weapon but not player

Tags: game-engine

I try to make an fps game. I dont shoot bullets, instead i use rays and a python script.

Now i want to add a weapon in front of the player and if the player shoots it should animate the weapon but i cant figure out how to do that.

When i set the player to be parent of the weapon, the whole player moves, if i dont parent it, the weapon stays at its position and dont follow the player.

How can i archive this accordingly?

[image]

EDIT: Done

Comment: Usually in FPS the weapon is not on the same scene as the character, try to add an overlay scene with the weapon on it.

Comment: Thank you, i already fixed that. It was just a wrong parenting. I has it in front of the camera because its animated using empties in front of the camera. Maybe thats not best practice but its ok for me. I dont get any answers here so its hard for me to learn.

Comment: I recommend you to ask questions on Blender Artists forum, Game Engine section, there you will find an somewhat active BGE community. https://blenderartists.org/c/game-engine